# vim latex editing

Tags: vim, input-encodings

What do I do if my tex file now looks like:

```
^@\^@d^@o^@c^@u^@m^@e^@n^@t^@c^@l^@a^@s^@s^@[^@1^@1^@p^@t^@]^@{^@a^@r^@t^@i^@c^@l^     @e^@}^@
   2 ^@ 
   3 ^@\^@u^@s^@e^@p^@a^@c^@k^@a^@g^@e^@{^@a^@m^@s^@m^@a^@t^@h^@,^@ ^@a^@m^@s^@s^@y^@m^     @b^@,^@ ^@e^@u^@c^@a^@l^@,^@ ^@y^@f^@o^@n^@t^@s^@,^@ ^@s^@e^@t^@s^@p^@a^@c^@e^@,^@      ^@s^@e^@c^@t^@s^@t^@y^@,^@ ^@e^@n^@u^@m^@i^@t^@e^@m^@,^@ ^@a^@m^@s^@c^@d^@,^@ ^@
   4 ^@ ^@ ^@w^@a^@s^@y^@s^@y^@m^@,^@ ^@c^@a^@p^@t^@i^@o^@n^@,^@ ^@t^@i^@k^@z^@,^@ ^@t^     @i^@k^@z^@-^@q^@t^@r^@e^@e^@,^@ ^@m^@a^@t^@h^@t^@o^@o^@l^@s^@,^@ ^@i^@n^@c^@o^@n^@     s^@o^@l^@a^@t^@a^@,^@ ^@p^@g^@f^@p^@l^@o^@t^@s^@,^@ ^@
   5 ^@ ^@ ^@t^@i^@k^@z^@-^@3^@d^@p^@l^@o^@t^@,^@ ^@f^@l^@o^@a^@t^@,^@ ^@w^@r^@a^@p^@f^     @i^@g^@,^@ ^@m^@u^@l^@t^@i^@r^@o^@w^@,^@ ^
```

Comment: I believe the word is 'panic.'

Comment: Actually, it looks like the text is all there, but each character is prepended with `^@`, some kind of control character (my guess a jump from a 16-bit encoding to n 8-bit encoding).  Was this sent to you by someone else?

Comment: Find and replace `^@` by nothing, or use the restore command from your verison control (or backup) system.

Comment: @SeanAllred how I do fix this?

Comment: @Caramdir if such a system is even in place.  Try to use vim to open it up in UTF-16 from the get-go; I use Emacs, so the best I could give you is a Google search.

Comment: @SeanAllred: Actually vim should recognize UTF-16 files automatically (at least it does on my system) and display them correctly. Maybe the `^@`s are already written to the file? Then search-and-replace is probably the only option.

Answer (score 9):

It has been saved as utf-16 and so every other byte is 0 (often displayed as ^@ as @ has code 64 so zero is control-@)

The only thing I know about vim is that it isn't emacs but in chat my backup vim expert suggests

```
:set fileencoding=utf-8
:set encoding=utf-8
```

Comment: @Dacid Carlisle so how do I fix this?

Comment: Do you know how to have vim open it up in UTF-16 from the get-go?

Comment: `iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 -o output.tex file.tex` should work

Comment: @David Carlisle I ran those commands in Vim on the file but nothing happened.

Comment: @Caramdir run that from the terminal as `iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 -o /path/to/new/file /path/to/old`?

Comment: @dustin: yes. You can test David's suspicion with `file /the/tex/file.tex` first (assuming you are on Linux).

Comment: @Caramdir what? `file /the/file`?

Comment: @dustin: The `file` command displays information about a file (such as the encoding, if it can be guessed).

Comment: @dustin you need to check if the file really does have every other byte 0 (and is in utf16) or if it has been through something that has corrupted it so it literally has `^@` before every character. (As posted in your question it is literally `^@` not a null byte displayed as that. In the latter case you can just use  vim search/replace to replace ^@ by nothing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it came back as file: data

Comment: @dustin: I think we need to know what OS you are using.  If you can run the CLI program "hexdump" (or some other byte-oriented file-contents display program - Emacs has one built in, of course) then `hexdump -C file.tex` will show you whether each other character is 00.